# How do I Get with using string parameter?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I currently have a web api Get method using EF6 and it is accepting an int parameter called serial. Instead of the primary key serial I want to find extserial from the URI.

Here is my Get where I have localhost/api/AH?serial=1

```
// GET api/AH/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Transmital))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetTransmital(int Serial)
        {
            Transmital transmital = db.Transmitals.Find(Serial);
            if (transmital == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(transmital);
        }
```

I need to have it get by localhost/api/AH?ExtSerial=ABC123

For some reason it won't take the following

```
// GET api/AH/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Transmital))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetTransmital(string ExtSerial) //or [FromUri]string ExtSerial
        {
            Transmital transmital = db.Transmitals.Find(ExtSerial);
            if (transmital == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(transmital);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use IHttpActionResult interface.

Try this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetTransmitalsExtSerial([FromUri] string ExtSerial)
        {
            //return Ok(ExtSerial.ToString());
            return Ok(db.Transmitals.Where(exs => exs.ExtSerial == ExtSerial));
        }
```